# Can't pass right ID to .replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I know the answer is probably gonna be something very simple but i'm losing my mind over not getting this to work:

```
<button id="buttonid<?php echo $i?>" onclick="addShift(this.id)">+</button>
<script>
    function addShift(id){
        alert(id);
        $('#id').replaceWith( "<h2>TEST</h2>" );        
    }
</script>
```

alert shows the right ID. But i can't get the .replaceWith function to work.

```
$("button").replaceWith( "<h2>TEST</h2>" );
```

This is working by the way. What am i substantially missing here about submitting html ID's to javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be misunderstanding the problem, but I think it's because you are using the string `'#id`' instead of the value for `id`.

Try this:

```
<button id="buttonid<?php echo $i?>" onclick="addShift(this.id)">+</button>
<script>
    function addShift(id){
        alert(id);
        $('#'+id).replaceWith( "<h2>TEST</h2>" );        
    }
</script>
```

You might be thinking that Javascript works like PHP in terms of supporting string interpolation. That means, the thing that let's you do something like `$variable = 'me'; echo "$variable is cool";` in PHP, and have it print out `me is cool`. But Javascript doesn't do that. You need to use string concatenation instead, i.e. `alert(variable + ' is cool')`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was something simple but i couldn't get to it. You saved the day!